# ¿Cómo usar una expresion regular para reemplazar espacio en blanco del inicio de una cadena por #?

Tags: java, regex

Ante todo un cordial saludo, y gracias de ante mano, 
estoy intentando realizar un `replaceAll`, para remplazar todos los espacios en blanco al inicio de una cadena de string por `#`, pero la expresion solo me cambia el primer espacio de la cadena:

```
"detalleLinea": ""             COMPROBANTE DE VENTA CON PIN                          "
```

Uso el código

```
row.setDetalleLinea(rs[2].replace("\"", "").replaceAll("^\\s+","#"));
```

y obtengo este resultado:

```
"detalleLinea": "#COMPROBANTE DE VENTA CON PIN                          ",
```

Comment: Esa expresión regular, ¿la entiendes? Como está, sólo va a reemplazar un espacio en blanco que esté al comienzo de la cadena. Por favor, indica cómo buscas que quede la cadena al final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como solo quieres reemplazar los espacios iniciales, considero que entonces usar una expresión regular junto con los métodos `String.replace*()` para lograr esto no es factible, puesto que estos métodos aplican la expresión regular exhaustivamente sobre toda la cadena. Esto quiere decir que, aunque puedas encontrar alguna regex que supuestamente te ayude, siempre habrá algún caso en que falle.

Por tal motivo te propongo que implementes un método de utilidad que te ayude con esto.

```
    public static String replaceAllLeading(String str, char replacement) {
        int length = str.length();
        var strCharArr = str.toCharArray();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < length && Character.isWhitespace(strCharArr[i])) {
            strCharArr[i] = replacement;
            i++;
        }

        return String.copyValueOf(strCharArr);
    }
```

Luego puede hacer algo así

```
var str = "             COMPROBANTE DE VENTA CON PIN                          ";
System.out.println(replaceAllLeading(str, '#'));
```

*Salida*
`#############COMPROBANTE DE VENTA CON PIN`

**OJO**: Los espacios en blanco del final no se eliminan.

Comment: si efectivamente eso es lo que necesito, que solo remplace los espacios en blanco del inicio de la cadena todos, por #, solo me remplaza el primer caracter, trate de usar * , pero obtengo el mismo resultado

Comment: @VíctorEduardoDuqueRosales listo, ahora si hace lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacerlo de las siguientes formas, primero la más elegante con `\s` más un espacio y en su lugar reemplazando con dos `#` **o** simplemente dos espacios seguidos, reemplazados por dos `##`:

```java
        String texto = "        COMPROBANTE DE VENTA CON PIN        ";
        texto = texto.replaceAll("\\s ", "##"); //Así se ve mas elegante 
      //texto = texto.replaceAll("  ", "##"); //dos espacios, mismo resultado que arriba
        System.out.println(texto);
```

Con `\s` encuentras un carácter de espacio (incluye espacio, tabular, nueva página, nueva línea, entre otros), por lo mismo cuando dos espacios estén juntos, se reemplaza con un `#`.

```java
    texto.replaceAll("\\s ", "#");
```

Pero existe un pequeño problema, en lo anterior ya que este reemplazará 2 espacios que se encuentren juntos con un solo `#`

**ENTRADA**

```
"        COMPROBANTE DE VENTA CON PIN        "
```

**SALIDA**

> "####COMPROBANTE DE VENTA CON PIN####"

La entrada posee 8 espacios en blanco ya sea en el inicio como al final de la misma, pero solo se muestran 4 a cada lado.

Por lo mismo la cantidad de espacios, sea la misma cuando la cadena sea formateada, he puesto que para cada dos espacios reemplace con dos `##`

```java
 texto = texto.replaceAll("\\s ", "##"); 
 texto = texto.replaceAll("  ", "##");
```

---

Con todo lo anterior :

**ENTRADA**

```
"        COMPROBANTE DE VENTA CON PIN        "
```

**SALIDA**

> "########COMPROBANTE DE VENTA CON PIN########"

Fuente : [Expresiones regulares](https://jarroba.com/busqueda-de-patrones-expresiones-regulares/)